# How to check string for requirements WITHOUT regex in python?

Tags: python, string, passwords

I need to make a program that checks an input (password) with the following requirements:

> - at least 8 characters in length
> - contains at least one lowercase letter
> - contains at least one uppercase letter
> - contains at least one number

It should return false if any of the requirements are not satisfied.

So far i have made the following just for the first requirement.

```
def check_password(pword):
   if len(pword) < 8:
       return False
   for i in pword:
       if pword[i].isUpper():
           print(True)
   return True
```

I don't know how to implement the other requirements without using regex.

Comment: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-check-if-python-string-contains-another-string,  Check this..? print(len(pword))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **any** statement returns `True` if your string has at least one match, in this case, one uppercase, lowercase and digit character requirements. Then the **all** statement returns `True` only if all the conditions are met.

```
def check_password(pword):
    return all([
        len(pword) >= 8,
        any(letter.isupper() for letter in pword),
        any(letter.islower() for letter in pword),
        any(letter.isdecimal() for letter in pword) 
    ])

check_password('a4R') # False
check_password('abcdefgh') # False
check_password('12345678') # False
check_password('ABCDEFGH') # False
check_password('abcDEFGH') # False
check_password('abc45678') # False
check_password('ABC45678') # False
check_password('abcDEF7')  # False
check_password('abcDEF78') # True
check_password('abc12345')  # False
```

Comment: thanks!! and quick note, your operator should be >= 8. thank you! it worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `if` statements asking for what you want, for example:

```py
def check_password(pword):
    if not len(pword) >= 8:
        return False
    elif not any(char.islower() for char in pword):
        return False
    elif not any(char.isupper() for char in pword):
        return False
    elif not any(char.isdigit() for char in pword):
        return False
    else:
        return True

print(check_password(''))  # False
print(check_password('HELLOOOOOO'))  # False
print(check_password('abc12345'))  # False
print(check_password('Helllooooo'))  # False
print(check_password('Hello12345'))  # True
```

Comment: thanks for this! however when i try abc12345, it returns true. it should be false.

Comment: @matmatpancakes yeah, it's my bad, using `all` is not a good idea, is better not `any`, see update.